# Overriding the floor division operator

Tags: python, operators, overriding

I'm trying to make a simple Python code or shell that will allow me to use it as a calculator...for circuit analysis. Ideally, I would use Python's normal calculator to calculate equivalent resistances based on the notation: R1 + R2 means two resistors in series, whereas R1//R2 means two resistors in parallel. Hopefully, this means that I can use Python as usual, such as:

```
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> R1 = 1
>>> R2 = 2
>>> R1 + R2
3
```

So series resistances would be simple enough (duh). However, when it comes to resistors in parallel, I would like to use the floor-division as the operator, which would allow for normal arithmetic combinations:

```
>>> 2 // 2
1
>>> (R2 // 2) + R1
2
```

Where the // division is defined as:

```
def __floordiv__(self, other):
    return 1/(1/self.value + 1/other)
```

After doing some research, I understand that built-in classes such as integers and doubles cannot be overridden. However, I don't really want to subclass because that would lose the ease of simply typing the value of the resistance as a primitive type. Is there any other way I could accomplish this? I would like this to be a temporary effect, that only exists in a small scope and can be executed at the start of a shell file. Thanks!

Comment: The resistance isn't a primitive type, so you won't be able to just type it in unless you manage to monkey-patch `int`. I think doing `R(1) + R(2)` and `R(1) | R(2)` is simpler and clearer.

Answer (score 4):

It's better to go with subclasses. With int/doubles you won't be able to use other elements beside resistors. You can create classes with very short name like "R" or resistors, "C" for capacitors etc. This won't have lot of overhead and will be more readable

```
R(2) +  R(2) == R(4)
R(2) // R(2) == R(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object that will make it look more or less like you can use integer literals with a different meaning.

For example, if you define the operators for the `p` object right, you could, use syntax like this:

```
2 + (p/ 3 // 2 // 10) + 4
```

Alternatively, you could do something like this:

```
2 + (3 /_/ 2 /_/ 10) + 4
```

or even:

```
2 + (3 /_/ 2 // 10) + 4
```

I would probably only use this kind of "operator magic" in a project I'm doing on my own or if it improves readability enormously.